# how to add event handler in close button of accordion generated dynamically

Tags: jquery

i have an accordion which i created dynamically using jquery and added a close button on the header of the accordion which also has a event handler but the event handler doesn't get called when the close button is clicked
here is the html

```
<div class="main span10">
    <div class="well span4">
        <h2>Add New Bill</h2><hr/>
        <label>Bill Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="bill_number" placeholder="Enter The Bill Number"/>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3 " id="date" placeholder="Enter The Purchase Date"/>
        <label>Bill description</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="bill_description" placeholder="Enter The Item"/>
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter The Quantity"/>
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="price" placeholder="Enter The Price    "/>
        <br/>   
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit" id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="well span4" id="popup">
        <div id="accordion"></div><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
$('#myModal').hide();
$("#popup").hide();
$("#date").datepicker();
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({fillSpace:true,icons:{'header':'ui-icon-plus'},event:'mouseover'});

$('#add').click( function() {
    $("#popup").show();         
    var bn = $("#bill_number").val();
    var date=$("#date").val();          
    var bd=$("#bill_description").val();            
    var qn=$("#quantity").val();            
    var pr=$("#price").val();           
    var header="item "+indicator;           
    var total=qn*pr;            

    data = data+"\"item" + indicator+"\":[\""+bn+"\",\""+date+"\",\""+bd+"\",\""+qn+"\",\""+pr+"\","+"\""+total+"\"],";

    var description = "Bill description: "+bd+"<br>quantity: "+qn+"<br>price: "+pr+"";
    indicator++;            

    $("#accordion").append("<h3>"+header+"<a href='#' onclick='return false' class='close' id='acc_close'>x</a></h3><div>"+description+"</div>").accordion("refresh");
});


$("#save").click(function() {
    data=data.substring(0,data.length - 1);         
    data += '}';    
    alert(data);        

    $.post("add.php", {datas:data}, function(info,status) {
        $('#info').html(info);
    });
}
```

Comment: delegate event to closest static container using `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#accordion").append("<h3>"+header+"<a href='#' class='close' id='acc_close'>x</a></h3><div>"+description+"</div>").accordion("refresh");

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    // Perform close
});
```

Or

```
var el = $("<h3>"+header+"<a href='#' class='close' id='acc_close'>x</a></h3>");
$("#accordion").append(el);
$("#accordion").append("<div>"+description+"</div>");
el.children().first().click(function () {
    // Perform close
});
```

As a side note, if you say `return false` in the callback the close button will simply do nothing.

Comment: Not happening i still changed the anchor tag to button but its still not working

Comment: Sounds like you might need to target it specifically, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer when el.children().first() is called a span tag is selected so it just needed to add next() after first()

```
var el = $("<h3>"+header+"<a href='#' class='close' id='acc_close'>x</a></h3>");
$("#accordion").append(el);
$("#accordion").append("<div>"+description+"</div>");
el.children().first().next().click(function () {
    // Perform close
});
```